# Formatting output in terminal, removing empty lines and convert comma

Tags: bash, sed, terminal, formatting, tr

I have a output like this. And i need to format that output.

```
a
b
c

d
e
f
g
h

k
l
m
n
```

I need to remove empty lines and end lines.
 And format the output like this.

```
a,b,c
d,e,f,g,h
k,l,m,n
```

i have tried different sed and tr commands but i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: ah sorry it is a mistake

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way is to use awk:

```
awk -v RS= -F '\n' -v OFS=, '{ $1 = $1 } 1' filename
```

The trick is in the various special variables:

- An empty `RS` means that records in the input are separated by empty lines.
- `-F '\n'` sets `FS` to `\n`, which means that fields in input records are separated by newlines.
- Setting `OFS` to `,` means that fields are to be separated by commas in the output.
- `ORS` is a newline by default, so records in the output are separated by newlines.

In the code, `$1 = $1` forces awk to reassemble the record so that all this is actually applied. The result is that the records are read as newline-separated fields of records separated by empty lines and printed as comma-separated fields of newline-separated records (i.e., CSV).

You could also do it with sed:

```
sed ':a /\n$/! { N; $! ba; }; s///; s/\n/,/g' filename
```

This reads new lines and appends them to the pattern space until an empty line or the end of the file is found, then removes the extra newline at the end (if it is there, which it won't be at the end of the file) and replaces the remaining newlines with commas. Mind you, I don't recommend doing it this way because awk is conceptually a better fit. The input data is tabular, after all, and awk excels at handling that kind of data.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use `paste`:

```
paste -sd, file | sed 's/,,,*/\n/g'
```

Output:

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
k,l,m,n
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/\n$/!s/\n/,/;ta;P;d' file
```